# Using YUI in Javascript, How do I draw overlays on datatable/ScrollingDataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I need to draw overlays spanning one or more rows on YUI datatable/scrollingdatable based on the mouse activity ( drag and drop ).

I have no issues with drawing overlays on top of datatable.

But I want the overlays to be moving along with the rows when I scroll the datatable. As of now after drawing the overlays they remain static irrespective of the movement of the datatable scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

You can align your overlay to a specific dom element using the `context` property. It sounds like this is what you want to do. There is more information about this in the [Overlay documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/overlay/#position).

Your code would look something like this:

```
var myOverlay = new YAHOO.widget.Overlay("myOverlay", {
    context: ['cellId', 'tl', 'bl']
});
```

This would anchor the top left (`tl`) corner of the overlay to the bottom left (`bl`) corner of 'cellId', where 'cellId' is some element in the table row that you want to align with.